# How to change my domain from 192.168.1.0/24 to 192.168.21.0/24

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp, subnet

We are about to start using hosting service for the software we use and they've asked us to change it.

I'm sure I can figure out how to change the DHCP scope, but that's not what I'm worried about.

All the copiers/printers have static IP's. I assume I'll have to change those. I have used GPO to assign printers. Will those also have to be updated?

I've already talked to the phone vendor and that won't be a problem.

Currently we host our software and users use RDP to connect to the server. How will that be affected? Will it just be a matter of telling them to change 192.168.1.4 in RDP to 192.168.21.4?

Will outlook be able to find Exchange and function properly? I'm worried that they're all looking at 192.168.1.2 and won't be able to find 192.168.21.2.

Shared drives won't need to be remapped, will they?

Any considerations, or things I could possible be looking over? We have a single site so that doesn't complicate things. We have a sonicwall TZ190 firewall. 4 servers, lots of PC's and printers, we host our own exchange and use RDP for our software.

If you need any further info please ask. I'd really appreciate some help here. Thank you.

Comment: Umm... now... 192.168.1.0/24 is the most common private subnet, but surely they're not asking every customer to change their internal IP scheme.

Comment: Right, I wish we were using a less common subnet. They said 192.168.21.0/24 was the available on their firewall, but 192.168.1.0/24 was already in use.

Comment: NAT could easily be used to avoid this, unless it is embedding IP addresses in an application layer (iSCSI does this). Still, probably not the worst idea for you to change, but I'd try and get away from 192.168 altogether.

Comment: Way far away in time we had a setup with transparent auto dial-in to customers networks. So we need customers to be on separate private networks so when we tried to connect to a host on a customer's network the router initiated a on-demand-dial-in connection. I thought these times are over.

Answer (score 0):

It dependes of your scenario. Depends if you manage your infraestructure using names or using IPS.

As example, if you mapped your network drives using \\Server\Folder you wont have to re map. Everything will work automatically. If you mapped your networks drives using \\192.168.1.30\Folder they will fail and you will need to re map.

In the case of RDP you wont have any problem.. tell your users the new address and in the future try to do not use IPS, no matter if are IPv4 or IPv6, use names.

Regards.